# undefined function (PHP)

Tags: function, include, required

I'll appreciate if somebody help me to find what is wrong in this code:

The function 'freightPrice' (shown below) is in a file called 'freight.php' and this file is required_once on 'main.php'. 
When I call the function 'freightPrice' from 'main.php' I receive the messages below:

main.php - "Undefined function 'FreightPrice'".

freightPrice.php - "Variable 'FreightPrice' might have not been defined".

freightPrice.php - "Undefined variable 'FreightPrice'".

```
<?php

// file freightPrice.php

// FREIGHT CALCULATION

function FreightPrice($weight) {

    $PriceList = array(
        0 => 0,
        1 => 50.65,
        2 => 52.51,
        3 => 55.47,
        4 => 58.43,
        5 => 61.39,
        6 => 63.21,
        7 => 66.01,
        8 => 68.82,
        9 => 71.63,
        10 => 74.40
     );

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 66; $i++) {
        if ($i == round($weight, 0)) {
            $freightPrice = $PriceList[$i];
            break;
        }
    }

    return $freightPrice;

}

freightPrice(60);
echo $freightPrice;

?>
```

Comment: correction: requere_once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this. Note capital F on the function name to fix the first error. The variable `$freightPrice` only exists in the scope of the function so you need to return it into a new version of the variable within current scope.

```
$freightPrice = FreightPrice(60); 
echo $freightPrice;
```

Comment: Mike the problem was the scope. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure from your snippet as to what you're trying to achieve...

firstly,

```
freightPrice(60); //doesn't point to a valid function (case-sensitive).
echo $freightPrice; //this is undefined in a global scape
```

i tend to use include(); function instead.

therefore, if you want to test it, just have

```
include("freightPrice.php");
echo FreightPrice(60);
```